# Preposition "in": what article to use if the following noun is masculine?

Tags: word-usage, preposition, article

Examples with feminine and neuter genders:

> Ich gehe in die Schule.
>      Ich gehe ins (in das) Restaurant.

But what to use with masculine gender?

> Ich gehe in den Bahnhof.

Is it correct to say *in den?*

Comment: As the question is right now, there is nothing more to answer than “yes”. Why do you think, that *in den* could not be correct?

Comment: For what possible reason should the preposition depends on the gender?

Comment: You are essentially asking what the accusative case of “der Bahnhof”, and, yes, it is “den Bahnhof”.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, I mean that with neuter gender `in` becomes `ins` (`in` + `das`). I thought that `in den` should join into something `in` + `den`. But I couldn't join them as `inn` :) So I thought I would better ask.

Comment: @Em1 For the reason of actual usage. In the case of `in + dative`, the preposition *word* does indeed depend on the gender. „Ich gehe im Bahnhof“ aber „Ich gehe in der Schule.“.

Answer (score 1):

"in" can also take the dative case.

Ich gehe in den Bahnhof.  Bald bin ich im (in dem) Bahnhof.

In the first case, the subject is moving, hence the accusitive is used. In the second, you just are somewhere, so it's dative.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the case of the following noun. The preposition `in` demands accusative or dative.

**`in` + dative**

The preposition has the form `im` incorporating the article `dem`.

> Ich gehe *im* Park spazieren.

**`in` + accusative**

The preposition keeps the form `in` not incorporating the article `den`.

> Ich gehe *in den* Park, um Martin zu treffen.

Answer (score 1):

Auf die Frage

> Wo gehst du (denn) hin?

antwortet man normalerweise

> Ich gehe zum Bahnhof.

und nicht

> Ich gehe in den Bahnhof.

Comment: Das beantwortet die Frage nicht und erscheint auch in diesem Zusammenhang nicht erheblich.

Answer (score -1):

Prepositions only get a 's' ending if the referred noun is singular and neuter.
Some examples:

> Ich gehe in`s` (in das) Theater. (n)
> Ich gehe in die Schule. (f)
> Ich gehe in den Park. (m)
>
> Er steht auf`s` Podest. (n)
> Er steht auf die Bühne. (f)
> Er steht auf den Lastwagen. (m)

Edit: the last three lines are not correct German. They should rather be

> Er steht auf dem Podest. (n)  -- Nominativ = das Podest
>
> Er steht auf der Bühne. (f)  -- Nominativ = die Bühne
>
> Er steht auf dem Lastwagen. (m)  -- Nominativ = der Lastwagen

Comment: Richtig ist: Er steht auf dem Podest/auf der Bühne/auf dem Lastwagen. Das sind wo-Angaben (Dativ) und keine wohin-Angaben (Akkusativ).

Comment: Genau, da habe ich nicht ganz aufgepasst. Ich habe mir ein bisschen schwer getan mit den Beispielen :)

Comment: You are posting wrong German. `Er steht auf die Bühne` is not correct. Nor is `Er steht auf den Lastwagen`, unless he can stand on multiple `Lastwagen` at any one time. Please take more care when posting answers.